# is the xsi: prefix assumed to be known in XML?

Tags: xml, namespaces, schema

Working on an XML parser, I see a lot of XML files using the xsi:schemaLocation attribute without declaring the xsi namespace.

Is it an error or is there a spec stating it is assumed to be known before parsing? Grepping the namespaces spec for "xsi" gives no results, but maybe the answer is in another document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No namespaces [other than the XML namespace] can be assumed to be known.

If a document contains an `xsi` prefix, there should also be an associated namespace (which would normally be `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`).

If the namespace is not declared, the XML file is not valid.

Comment: Thanks, I know proving something doesn't exists is hard, but do you have some reference doc alluding to that? I might have a heated argument with some software editor, and I might need something to show.

Comment: @nraynaud - A proof of absence - the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl) do not mention this as a known namespace.

Comment: Correct answer, except that there is one predefined namespace which always exists, the one known by the prefix "xml". Edited the answer to add this rider.