# Can't convert XML to Json using online tools

Tags: xml, json

I have a XML data like below,

```
                      <Request>
                        <SourceCredentials>
                           <SourceName>{SourceName}</SourceName>
                           <Password>{Password}</Password>
                           <SiteIDs>
                              <int>{SiteID}</int>
                           </SiteIDs>
                        </SourceCredentials>
                        <UserCredentials>
                           <Username>{Username}</Username>
                           <Password>{Password}</Password>
                           <SiteIDs>
                              <int>{SiteID}</int>
                           </SiteIDs>
                        </UserCredentials>
                        <XMLDetail>Full</XMLDetail>
                        <PageSize>10</PageSize>
                        <CurrentPageIndex>0</CurrentPageIndex>
                        <ClientID>snarf</ClientID>
                        <Test>true</Test>
                        <CartItems>
                           <CartItem>
                              <DiscountAmount>4</DiscountAmount>
                              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                              <Item xsi:type="Service">
                                 <ID>000123</ID>
                              </Item>
                           </CartItem>
                        </CartItems>
                        <Payments>
                           <PaymentInfo xsi:type="CreditCardInfo">
                              <CreditCardNumber>{CreditCardNumber}</CreditCardNumber>
                              <Amount>5</Amount>
                              <BillingAddress>123 Happy Ln</BillingAddress>
                              <BillingCity>San Luis Obispo</BillingCity>
                              <BillingState>CA</BillingState>
                              <BillingPostalCode>93405</BillingPostalCode>
                              <ExpYear>2014</ExpYear>
                              <ExpMonth>7</ExpMonth>
                              <BillingName>Bob Joe</BillingName>
                           </PaymentInfo>
                        </Payments>
                     </Request>
```

I need to convert these to json format.

When i was using online tools i have got an error like below,

```
Unable to format the JSON output. The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "Item" is not bound.
```

I have used the below online tools,

[freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html)

[utilities-online.info](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.U_M4_XWSwok)

Its getting the success answer when i am skipping the statement `xsi:type` . But i need to convert as it is?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't valid XML hence wouldn't convert successfully. You need to have `xsi` prefix defined somewhere in your XML to make it valid namespace prefix.

For example, having the prefix declared at the XML root element, your XML successfully converted to JSON using [Freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.htm) tool :

```
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ....
    <CartItems>
       <CartItem>
          <DiscountAmount>4</DiscountAmount>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Item xsi:type="Service">
             <ID>000123</ID>
          </Item>
       </CartItem>
    </CartItems>
    ....
</Request>
```

Related discussion : [is the xsi: prefix assumed to be known in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533034/is-the-xsi-prefix-assumed-to-be-known-in-xml)

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.htm is not working now.