# Error in xml when using xpath .. The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "value" is not bound

Tags: xml, xpath

Using this xpath expression: `//items/item[@key='NAME']/value/text()`

on ..

```
<test>
  <items>
    <item key="USGAE">
      <value xsi:type="ns9:string">SomeUse</value>
    </item>
    <item key="NAME">
      <value xsi:type="ns9:string">TheName</value>
    </item>
  </items>
</test>
```

gives this error:

```
Error on line 4: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "value" is not bound.
```

However using the same xpath on ..

```
<test>
  <items>
    <item key="USGAE">
      <value>SomeUse</value>
    </item>
    <item key="NAME">
      <value>TheName</value>
    </item>
  </items>
</test>
```

gives me the right value: `TheName`

Why is that so? The server actually returns the first snippet of `XML` i.e with `xsi` inside each `value`

Is there a way around this? I don't have access to the web service that generates this `XML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, you need to add definition of `xsi` prefix to your XML document somehow.

Normally, XML parser only works given well-formed XML document, and a well-formed XML has **all namespace prefixes defined**. Despite widely used, `xsi` prefix is no exception, only `xml` prefix assumed to be known ([is the xsi: prefix assumed to be known in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533034/is-the-xsi-prefix-assumed-to-be-known-in-xml)).