# Is there anything wrong with this xml block?

Tags: xml

For some reasons i'm throwing an error on it..A validation error occured in an XML layout file

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="gbp_success_page-block">
```

My whole XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<body> 
    <referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="gbp_success_page-block"> 
            <arguments> 
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">gbp_success_page</argument> 
            </arguments> 
        </block> 
    </referenceContainer> 
</body>
```

Is it something to do with the xsi type?

Comment: What tool / programming language are you using to "process" this XML? And what does this "processing" really do?? You need to provide a **lot more** relevant info for anyone to be able to help ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a namespace prefix in the argument name xsi:type in line 6. This namespace  is not defined. 
Please see answer to [is the xsi: prefix assumed to be known in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533034/is-the-xsi-prefix-assumed-to-be-known-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on [online xml formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) and the returned message is "Unable to parse any XML input. Error on line 1: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "argument" is not bound."

If you remove the `xsi:type="string"` it becomes valid. So, yes, there is something wrong with the xml and it has to do with the xsi type.